# Count of value while taking the group by

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table:

```
PCdID    PSID   PlateNo   dtime 
1        100     15     2014-03-02 07:49:38.000
1        101     16    2014-03-05 07:49:38.000
1        100     15    2014-03-10 07:49:38.000
2        102    108    2014-03-11 07:49:38.000
1        101     16    2014-03-20 07:49:38.000 
1        101     16    2014-03-13 07:49:38.000
```

I want to get distinct values and counts so I write:

```
select t.PCdID,t.PSID,t.PlateNo from Transaction_tbl t  where dtime >='2014-01-01'
group by PCdID,PSID,PlateNo order by PSID,PlateNo
```

My output is:

```
PCdID    PSID   PlateNo   
    1        100     15     
    1        101     16
    2        102     108
```

But I'm expecting:

```
 PCdID    PSID   PlateNo   count 
    1        100     15     2
    1        101     16     3
    2        102     108    1
```

How can I rewrite my query?

Comment: I cannot believe that you haven't tried `Count(*)` if you want to have the count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a `COUNT(*)` in to the `SELECT`:

```
select t.PCdID, t.PSID, t.PlateNo, COUNT(*) as count
from Transaction_tbl t  
where dtime >='2014-01-01'
group by PCdID,PSID,PlateNo 
order by PSID,PlateNo
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select t.PCdID, t.PSID, t.PlateNo, COUNT(PlateNo) as Plate Count
from Transaction_tbl t  
where dtime >='2014-01-01'
group by PCdID,PSID,PlateNo 
order by PSID,PlateNo
```

**output**

```
PCdID    PSID   PlateNo Plate Count 

1        100     15     2
1        101     16     3
2        102     108    1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select t.PCdID,t.PSID,t.PlateNo , count(*) Count
from Transaction_tbl t  
where dtime >='2014-01-01'
group by PCdID,PSID,PlateNo 
order by PSID,PlateNo
```